Pandas outer merge
I have two data frames
dataframe 1
col1 col2
1     A    
1     B    
2     C  
5     Z
4     Q

dataframe 2
col1 col2 
1     A    
1     B    
2     E
3     X 
4     R
4     S   

I am performing an outer merge
merge = pd.merge(dataframe1, datagrame2, on="col1", how='outer')

I get
col1 col2_x col2_y
1       A       A
1       A       B
1       B       A
1       B       B
2       C       E
5       Z       NAN
3       NAN     X
4       Q       R
4       Q       S

How do I get the output as below
col1 col2_x col2_y
1       A       A
1       B       B
2       C       E
5       Z       NAN
3       NAN     X
4       Q       R
4       Q       S

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

your issue is logical, you are doing an outer join on two dataframes that have multiple occurrences of their keys (col1 in this case).
You could create an auxiliary column that helps you drop the duplicates of your outer join.
here is what you are missing after creating your dataframes (EDITED):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create the dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 1, 2, 5, 4],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Z', 'Q'],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'E', 'X', 'R', 'S'],
})

# Merge the dataframes
merged_df = (
    pd
    .merge(df, df2, on='col1', how='outer')
    .replace(np.nan, 'NaN', regex=True)
)

# display(merged_df)
merged_df['temp'] = list(zip(merged_df['col2_x'], merged_df['col2_y']))
merged_df['temp'] = merged_df['temp'].apply(sorted)
merged_df = merged_df.drop_duplicates(subset='temp', keep=False)

merged_df = merged_df.drop(columns='temp')

print(merged_df)

This should get you the output you are looking for.
I hope this helps!

I have edited the post. The above solution produces NAN if df has 1 row and df2 has 2 rows corresponding to the same col1(join). Is there a way I can get the edited output?

Yes you are right, since we are matching col1 and a temporary column, I modified the code accordingly, I hope that will solve your issue,

With a concat/ffill :
def dedup(df, suff):
    return (df.set_index("col1", append=True)
              .add_suffix(f"_{suff}"))

out = (
    pd.concat(
        [
            df1.pipe(dedup, "x"),
            df2.pipe(dedup, "y"),
        ], axis=1, sort=True
    ).groupby(level=1).ffill()
    .reset_index(level=1)
)

Output :
   col1 col2_x col2_y
0     1      A      A
1     1      B      B
2     2      C      E
3     3    NaN      X
3     5      Z    NaN
4     4      Q      R
5     4      Q      S

[7 rows x 3 columns]

